# How to open a particular link with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to web scraping and I try to open a link with selenium:

On Google Chrome I use inspect on the button I want to open and I get the following information:

`<a href="/c#candidates?id=a6b0e325a499&amp;candidateFilter=4af15d8991a8" data-tn-link="true" data-tn-element="view-unread-candidates"><span class="jobs-u-font--bold">(4 awaiting review)</span></a>`

I try to get all the links with the same structure and open it so I can access its data

[image]
[image]

(I have several button with the same structure but different href that I need to see)

Also under `Properties` I can see `a` for the same button.

However I want to be more precise than just using as I want only those particular links mentioned above:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
```

Can anyone advise ?

Comment: Can you show an additional link or two so we can see what remains fixed and what changes between candidates? For example, is it only unread you care about? It sounds like you really want to be able to match all qualifying a tags and then click - will you be passing a list of ids for example?

Comment: Thanks I added image so you can see the structure. Actually candidateFilter is not the issue here.

Comment: This solved now?

Comment: not really didn't make it work I think I get the elements with xpath:

```xpath = "/html/body/div[@id='wrapper']/div[@id='page_frame']/div[@id='page_content']/div[@class='page-wrapper']/div[@id='mc']/div[@id='plugin_container_MainContent']/div[@class='plugin-hadesinternal']/div/div/div[@class='jobs-JobsTab-main']/table[@class='jT cSST']/tbody/tr[@class='job-row'][3]/td[@class='candidates']/div/a[1]"
    selected_option = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)```
But can't open in a new tab or open and return to my previous page or open with BeautifulSoup...

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: It's url after login... It's my personal account. How can I share it with you differently ?

Comment: no, you shouldn't share your personal details.

Comment: Ok @supputuri solution worked with xpath. I can open the link now the struggle is opening in a new tab but this is another topic. Thanks for your

Comment: KunduK has done what I would have done except it looks like relative links that need a domain concatenated as prefix. Then you can loop that list and driver.get each url.

Comment: you can open in a new tab easily with execute_script and pass javascript command for new tab

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42417215/6241235  where you concatenate the new url from your list as you loop

Comment: @QHarr when I do:  
```selected_option = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    selected_option.click()``` 
that works fine

however 

```selected_option = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    selected_option.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')``` nothing will happen. 
I don't see how to handle it with `driver.execute_script("window.open('');")`

Comment: driver.execute_script("window.open('" + url +  "');")

Comment: Thanks @QHarr. Working well. I just had to add an intermediary step in between. I will show full code so it's clearer

```selected_option = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath) 

url = selected_option.get_attribute("href")

driver.execute_script("window.open('" + url + "');")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `//a[@data-tn-element = 'view-unread-candidates']`, which will list all unread candidates.

If you want a specific candidate by candidate id then use the following xpath. And set the candidateId with the desired id.

```
candidateId = 'a6b0e325a499'
"//a[@data-tn-element = 'view-unread-candidates'][contains(@href,'id=" + candidateId + "')]"
```

Comment: There seems to be something off in your quotes, as `candidateId` is a different color. I think the python interpreter might get confused by it, but I'm not sure I haven't tested it

Comment: its the variable holding the candidate id.  @Reedinationer updated the answer for clear understanding.

Comment: Oh durrr it's just a concatenation. I usually use `"stuff {} more stuff".format(variable)` so it threw me off! Yeah, that would work I think. Not sure if OP has the `candidateId` beforehand though.

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("jobs-u-font--bold")
```

To get the `<span>`, since that seems like a unique class name (although I can't be sure from your post). Then you can reach the `<a>` level with

```
a_elem = elem.find_element_by_xpath("..")
```

Then you can `a_elem.click()` or whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. `elem = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("jobs-u-font--bold")` correctly returns a list of elements. I itterate in a loop and tried
```for e in elements:
        a_elem = e.parent
        a_elem.click()

    ```
it returns: `AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'click'`

Comment: @Solal Yeah, I must have gotten confused with beautifulsoup. After referencing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079765/how-to-find-parent-elements-by-python-webdriver) I think you can leverage the same technique

Comment: Thanks I am using xpath and an extension Xpath Helper to grep the Xpath :) 
Working well

Answer (score 1):

To access the anchor tag you can use css selector with attribute `data-tn-element="view-unread-candidates"` i believe it should be same for all anchor tag.

```
elements=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a[data-tn-element="view-unread-candidates"]')
for ele in elements:
    print(ele.get_attribute("href"))
```

Or if you want to use child element and then want to fetch the parent tag then try below code with xpath.

```
elements=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='jobs-u-font--bold']")
for ele in elements:
    print(ele.find_element_by_xpath("./parent::a").get_attribute('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

List elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@data-tn-element='view-unread-candidates']"));

```
    Iterator<WebElement> iter = elements.iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        WebElement item = iter.next();
        String href = item.getAttribute("href");
        System.out.println("href is " + href);
    }
}
```

And if you want to click the link with the particular href, then you can put the if condition after getting the href in the above code . When that condition will meet, click on the element.