# Python selenium how to get parent element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to find at "Road" text and get position parent about it.in the picture
[image: a busy cat]

```
My code get to "Road" text. but can't get to parent of position element
 T4 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('table#tableID4')
 T4.text
```

`Output:` `'Road\nRoad\n2\nRoad\nRoad\nRoad\nRoad\nRoad\nRoad\nRoad\nRoad\nRoad\nRoad\nRoad\nRoad\nRoad\nRoad\nRoad\nRoad\nRoad\nRoad\nRoad\nRoad\nRoad\nRoad\nRoad\nRoad\nRoad\nRoad'`

html tag:

```
<table id="tableID4">
            <tr id="bigTr"><td id="bigRoadTd_0_0" class="">
                                    <p style="display: none"></p>
                                    <div style="" class="tie"></div>
                                    <div style="display: none" class=""></div>
                                    <div style="display: none" class=""></div>
                                    <div style="display: none" class=""></div>
                                    <div style="" class="banker">Road</div>
                                </td><td id="bigRoadTd_1_0" class="">
                                    <p style="display: none"></p>
                                    <div style="display: none" class=""></div>
                                    <div style="display: none" class=""></div>
                                    <div style="display: none" class=""></div>
                                    <div style="display: none" class=""></div>
                                    <div style="" class="player">Road</div>
```

Comment: See same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079765/how-to-find-parent-elements-by-python-webdriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(
                        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID , 'bigRoadTd_0_0')))

parent = driver.find_element(By.ID,'bigRoadTd_0_0')
all_children = parent.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"div")
for child in all_children:
    print(child.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
```

Above will find the parent and parse the children for their outerhtml.

Also you wouldn't use css selector to find that specific child element, it would be:

```
element_html = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'banker').get_attribute('outerHTML')
```

These are the attributes available for By class:

```
ID = "id"
XPATH = "xpath"
LINK_TEXT = "link text"
PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT = "partial link text"
NAME = "name"
TAG_NAME = "tag name"
CLASS_NAME = "class name"
CSS_SELECTOR = "css selector"
```