# How can I select a date in a DatePicker with selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, datepicker

I want to select a date from this [DatePicker](https://www.ut.com.sv/reportes?p_auth=e5aOMQez&p_p_id=MenuReportesEstadisticos_WAR_CompletePublicReports&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_MenuReportesEstadisticos_WAR_CompletePublicReports_reportName=25cargosdelsistema) :

So far, I have been able to select today's date only. But I don't know how to select a specific date. From this I need to select yesterday's date. Here what I've done so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get('https://www.ut.com.sv/reportes?p_auth=vUIS4sqn&p_p_id=MenuReportesEstadisticos_WAR_CompletePublicReports&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_MenuReportesEstadisticos_WAR_CompletePublicReports_reportName=25cargosdelsistema')

elm = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Cargos del Sistema')
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
elm.click()

#TIPO
drpmedicion=driver.find_element_by_id('tipo')
drpmed=Select(drpmedicion)
driver.implicitly_wait(2)

drpmed.select_by_visible_text('Indicativo')
driver.implicitly_wait(2)

#SALIDA
drpsalida=driver.find_element_by_id('outType')
drpsal=Select(drpsalida)
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
drpsal.select_by_visible_text('csv')

#FECHAS INICIO
date1=driver.find_element(By.NAME,'fecha_desde')
date1.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
date1.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(2)

date2=driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'picker__button--today')
date2.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

#FECHAS FIN
date3=driver.find_element(By.NAME,'fecha_hasta')
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
date3.click()
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
date3.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

date4=driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'picker__button--today')
date4[1].click()

driver.implicitly_wait(5)


#CLICK FINAL
btn=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="portlet_FormularioReportesEstadisticos_WAR_CompletePublicReports"]/div/div/div/input')
btn.click()
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approach this a couple of ways, the easiest would be to get the element based on the attribute `data-pick` that the linked website uses:

```html
<td role="presentation">
    <div class="picker__day picker__day--infocus" data-pick="1590966000000" role="gridcell">1</div>
</td>
```

The value is the day's epoch equivalent in milliseconds which you can get like so (change it to whatever date format you use)

```py
import time
import datetime

selectedDate = "01/06/2020"
epoch = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(selectedDate, "%d/%m/%Y").timetuple()))*1000
```

Add the epoch value into your selector, get the parent element from there and click it.

The other way to click it would be to execute 'raw' Javascript via Selenium's [`execute_script`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script). `include/js/pickadate/picker.js` handles when you click on the date with an `on('click'...` event. You could invoke that by using a [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and then using the [`.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) method.

Comment: Could you expand a bit more on how to get the parent element? So far I have done a few things like: date=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[data-pick="1591164000000"') but now I can get the parent element to click it.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079765/how-to-find-parent-elements-by-python-webdriver) is probably the easiest way to get the parent. So from `date` you would get the xpath of `..` which should be one up from that element, thus the parent.