# How can I traverse to parent node from the current node in xpath?

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I have one xpath based on class and I'm trying to find the parent element of it from the current.

Path 1

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/p[8]/b[2]/a
```

Path 2

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/p[8]/b[2]
```

Path 1 can also represent using class name i.e. "xyz" `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="xyz"]')`

How can I traverse to parent node from the current node ?

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Does this answer solves your query? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079765/how-to-find-parent-elements-by-python-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the question *How can i traverse to parent node from the current node* is:

1. Use `/..` in your xpath. e.g. `//a[@class="xyz"]/..` - this will locate immediate parent of `a[@class="xyz"]`
2. `/parent::*` or `/parent::<tagname>` -  your xpath code should be `//a[@class="xyz"]/parent::*`

Comment: How about getting (printing) html tags inside the current node?

Comment: @BalB, Means ? what do you want to achieve ? If you are tying to print tag inside current node, it will print all child tags not parent.

Answer (score 0):

Due to XPath documentation, here is several options you could use:

`//a[@class="xyz"]/parent::tagname` - It will select only the parent element of the current node

`//a[@class="xyz"]/ancestor::tagname` - Give's you all ancestors (parents, grandparents, etc.) of the current node

`//a[@class="xyz"]/preciding-sibling::tagname` - Selects all siblings before the current node